# Capturar Enter no IE usando jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Galera tenho o seguinte código em jQuery:

```
    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which === 13) $('.button_ok').click();
    });
```

Quando eu clico na tecla enter, ele faz com que o usuário tenho clicado no botão da class `button_ok`.

Esta funcionando em todos os navegadores, menos no Internet Explorer. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Esta pergunta tem dois votos para fechar como não sendo clara o suficiente. Para mim, me pareceu ser bastante clara, então votei para manter aberta. Alguém que votou ou irá votar pelo fechamento, gostaria de se manifestar para explicar o que há de errado?

Comment: Ao verificar a aba Console do IE (F12), o navegador reporta algum erro depois que você digita algo? Se sim poste junto a sua pergunta.

Comment: Creio que seja necessário complementar o post dizendo qual é a versão do jQuery sendo usada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Segunda essa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492865/jquery-keypress-event-not-firing) encontrada no *So-En* `e.which` não funciona no *IE*.

Uma alternativa é você usar `e.KeyCode` e usar `keydown` em vez de `keypress`.

Pressione executar e vera que o alert irá te mostrar a mensagem: ***a tecla enter foi pressionada***.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
       if(e.keyCode == 13){
          alert('a tecla enter foi pressionada');
       }
    }, false);
```

Comment: o seu funcionou 100%, como fica isso em jQuery?

Comment: @HugoBorges segue [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r0c3r1pq/2/)

Comment: vlw mesmo :)    deu certo

Answer (score 2):

O problema que ocorre em seu código é que a função `which` não é suportada nas versões antigas do Internet Explorer, somente a partir da versão 9 dele.

Então para resolver seu problema, com uma solução simples e cross browser de captura da tecla enter, você pode fazer da seguinte forma abaixo:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if(keycode === 13){
        $('.button_ok').click();   
    }
});
```

```js
$(document).keypress(function(e){
  var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if(keycode === 13){
    $('.button_ok').click();   
  }
});

$('.button_ok').click(function() {
  alert('OK!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="txt_input" />
<input type="button" class="button_ok" value="OK" />
```

```js
    $(window).keypress(function(e){
      var keycode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
      if(keycode === 13){
        $('.button_ok').click();   
      }
    });

    $('.button_ok').click(function() {
      alert('OK!');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="button_ok" value="OK" />
```

Comment: tentei aqui e não deu certo

Comment: Será que não tem algum erro?

Comment: Coloquei um exemplo no post, verifica se não ajuda.

Comment: remove o campo `txt_input` e ele para de funcionar

Comment: Em qual versão do Internet Explorer você está usando?

Comment: é a versão 11.545.10586.0

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" value="texto do input" id="input">
<input type="button" value="click" id="click">

$('#click').on('click', function () {                    
 alert($('#input').val());
 });
 $('#input').on('keydown', function (e) {                     
     if (e.keyCode === 13) {
         $('#click').trigger('click');
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Eu utilizo muito isso com compatibilidade ao internet explorer:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('keydown', function(event) {
        if(event.which == 13) {
            suaAcao();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use o `e.keyCode`:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
     var code = e.keyCode || e.which; 
     if(code === 13) $('.button_ok').click();
});
```

Comment: tentei aqui e não deu certo